# What are the differences between "rugged" external HDDs and "regular" ones?

Tags: external-hard-drive, hardware-failure

Two example models (off the top of Amazon best seller list),
Western Digital Elements Portable (regular)
vs
Transcend 25M3 drive (rugged)

True, one is enclosed in rubber casing, the other is not. But when dropping it from let's say a height of one meter, mostly what matters is the impact of acceleration on its mechanical components inside, not the scratches on the casing. Therefore, I'm interested is there any difference in the disc drives itself between these (or any similar) models? And what those are?

Is "rugged" really rugged, more tolerant to falls and kicks? Within reasonable limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I was recently researching rugged tablets, here is a useful [article](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/rugged-IT) I found.

Rugged IT is a marketing term for hardware that is designed to operate in extremely harsh environments and conditions. There are three generally accepted levels of ruggedization: semi-rugged, fully-rugged and ultra-rugged. The levels describe a product's ability to survive drops, vibration, dust, immersion and extreme temperatures.

Semi-rugged devices, which are increasingly being called business-rugged by marketers, are usually enhanced versions of commercial off-the-shelf (COTS) hardware. The components are the same, but they are protected better.  For example, a semi-rugged laptop might have a thicker case, a gel-mounted hard disk drive and a spill-resistant keyboard. Fully-rugged devices are designed from the inside-out to work in extreme temperatures, to be impervious to being dropped, to resist shocks and vibrations and to be dustproof and waterproof. A fully-rugged laptop may have a solid state hard drive, which has no moving parts, runs cool and doesn’t need for a fan. (another moving part that adds weight to the device.)  Ultra-rugged devices, which are usually designed to meet precise specifications for military use, are made to handle the harshest environmental conditions. An ultra-rugged laptop can be left out in a sandstorm, frozen in a blizzard or sent on a vibrating rocket into space without any detrimental effects.

The levels of ruggardization are not standardized, which means that vendors have the freedom to use the labels as they see fit. Most vendors incorporate other values in their self-evaluations to provide potential customers with some assurance that their products deserve the label they have been given. The two most common values cited are from the Ingress Protection (IP) Code, a system for classifying the degrees of sealing protection provided by the enclosures of electrical equipment and MIL STD 810, a series of testing guidelines set by the U.S. Department of Defense for military and commercial equipment.

Comment: So, do those markings really make a difference in the real world (e.g. carrying a HDD with you in a shoulder bag vs carrying a regular one)?

Comment: I have had non-rugged portable hard drives that have lasted without issues.  Granted, I am fairly careful with my equipment.  I think if you are conscious of taking care of it, you shouldnt have an issue.

Comment: Same here. Had a number of "regular" external drives and handled them with some care and they're all still operational. But I'm interested, if I was to buy a "rugged" one, like the model above, what could I expect of it while still being relatively certain that it will work when I get home?

Comment: It looks like its *only* "rugged" for drop tests - it is drop-proof to military standard 810F Meth.516.5 Proc.IV Transit Drop, which specifies that the subject is dropped on each face, edge and corner, for a total of 26 drops, from a height of 122cm (4ft).

Answer (score 3):

How "rugged" a piece of consumer electronics is, is primarily marketing-speak.

From [Transcend's site](http://lb.transcend-info.com/products/Catlist.asp?modno=284&cat_no=190):

> The StoreJet 25M3 combines the shock-resistant qualities of Transcend’s award-winning rugged StoreJet M series with the SuperSpeed 5Gb/s interface bandwidth of USB 3.0, allowing users to enjoy ultra-fast file transfers and the highest level of anti-shock protection.

Info gleaned from PDF product specs and Google:

> Military-Grade Shock Resistance
>   • Designed to meet U.S. military drop
> test standards
>
> Advanced 3-stage shock protection system
>    • Combines a rugged
> slip-resistant silicone outer shell, a reinforced hard casing, and an
> internal hard drive suspension damper.

Here's a video from Transcend explaining what makes those drive "rugged": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f0gzPZDflw8

Most likely the "Military shock test" they are referring to is [MIL-STD-810](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-810):

> MIL-STD-810, Environmental Engineering Considerations and Laboratory Tests is a United States Military Standard that emphasizes tailoring an equipment's environmental design and test limits to the conditions that it will experience throughout its service life, and establishing chamber test methods that replicate the effects of environments on the equipment rather than imitating the environments themselves.

That Wikipedia article has [a good section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIL-STD-810#Applicability_to_.22Ruggedized.22_Consumer_Products) on how that MIL spec can be applied to "Ruggedized" consumer products.

> When queried, many manufacturers will admit no testing has actually been done and that the product is only designed/engineered/built-to comply with the standard. This is because many of the tests described can be expensive to perform and usually require special facilities.
>
> ...if some testing was actually done they would have to specify: (i) against which test methods of the standard the compliance is claimed; (ii) to which parameter limits the items were actually tested; and (iii) whether the testing was done internally or externally by an independent testing facility

As you can see in the Transcend specs above, it's "designed to meet", so it probably hasn't actually been *tested* for ruggedness at all.

Basically, you'd have to contact the manufacturer of each consumer product that makes a "ruggedized" claim and ask them if tests were actually done. If so, which tests from the MIL spec, and if it was tested by them or an external party.  Then take those answers and judge for yourself.

Good related article (as footnoted in the Wikipedia article licked above): [Rugged Notebook Computers - When a wimpy plastic clamshell notebook just won't do](http://ruggedpcreview.com/2_notebooks.html)

Comment: Good answer, but apart from the suspension damper I see nothing that tells anything new. Just marketing speak for a black box. Interested in the technical details.

Comment: @Idigas It's mostly marketing, I'll post some more info regarding the "military" drop specs they are most likely referring to.  Though "How" they meet those requirements (technically or otherwise) may be a trade secret.